# What is the difference in this example of Dereferencing pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

So my class has two examples, and not sure why one works and the other doesn't.

```
int numSides = 3;
int *valPointer = &numSides;
PrintValue(valPointer);
```

Prints 3.

```cpp
int numSides = 3;
int* valPointer;
*valPointer = &numSides;
PrintValue(valPointer);
```

This doesn't work, but why?

class note say `int` value can't be assigned `int*`.

Comment: This line: `*valPointer = &numSides`, attempts to assign the *address* of numSides to the memory pointed at by `valPointer`. Remember than an `int` cannot hold memory addresses (that's the job of pointers), which is why you get a compilation error. Additionally, note that `valPointer` is **uninitialized**, which means that assigning any value to it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: To be precise: `*valPointer = &numSides;` is _undefined behavior_, because an uninitialized pointer is dereferenced. No one can tell what actually happens.

Comment: `*valPointer = numSides;` would be undefined behavior; OTOH `*valPointer = &numSides;` is well-defined in that it will always result in a compile-time error.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int* valPointer;
*valPointer = &numSides;
```

The above is wrong -- you are trying to set (the integer-that-`valPointer`-points-to) to an address, which doesn't make sense, because addresses and integers are (generally speaking) not interchangeable.

Perhaps you meant this instead?

```
int* valPointer;
valPointer = &numSides;
```

... that would set `valPointer` to point to `numSides`.

Comment: but why is it doable with the first example. In the first example we say int *valPointer = &numSides;

Comment: @FranciscoGutierrezRamirez The why is in the types of the assignment: type on the left and type on the right, they have to be compatible. One is a pointer the other is an integer,

Comment: @FranciscoGutierrezRamirez in the first example you are declaring a pointer-to-int and assigning it to point to `numSides`.  You should interpret it as `int *` valPointer = &numSides;, not as int `*valPointer` = &numSides;   To put it another way, the `*` in the variable-declaration is part of the variable-type, whereas the `*` in the second example is a dereferencing-operator, which is a different thing entirely, even though it uses the same character.

Answer (score 0):

### The [program](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJMmkt6ADJ5amAHLGARpmKCADqgWF1tPYYmZhZePmp0tvZORq7unIrKmKp%2BDATMxAQBxqbmCSrhtKnpBJGOLm6CCmkZWUG5VcWl0bFcAJSKqAbEyBwA5ABuqHjoANQACsR2BABqbAaYEFMAVK3iAMyyAAwAguI7g8MjVBCtI%2BIA7FvbIyNTI7TGDMOYCmdrACIja%2BtXN3dL/TYYyG9DcPz21xGAKBIIIbjenykADYHkYnlgFOCdjcJlNZoYFoDWMCpm5VhsIRd3r12qwQL0AKy9UimXqbZmoek6ORyEYKTrdTBnSRrTjMgj09mtdoAazMSIAdAzuOduEjJEiABxIhlI86cc4WOm9bjMoxcTabFmSjn05kKEBWiVsmmkOCwGCIFCoIwePDsMgUCBoX3%2BirIYSiAD6BGIBloMtIVH9cOIDogzhtpGcdnSAE96WLSCGjFoCAB5WisAsu0hYIwiYDsLP4YhJNT9F5ZzAADySBjhheZpON7KEeGcxHzeiwQ9Isbw5t6YvaNHoTDYHB4/EEkbEPJk4%2BcDtgtGYpZAU9EL36a1InfcsfjMulpFQHgKDt6AFoquh1u8EgyHIkjMCM37lms9qJMkGgQFYtSmPEVhNOUcSkKEvh0IhnjeFhtCoTEFTxEo%2BQpNUmT6NklQwQURQZIRLQkRROHMY0dhlERcTtPyXQ9G0Qj0ky1q1pyvQ9tq35ItwIwRo2IwQE%2BCanBAuCECQwqiqQIx6KGAaaZwpzcsBMjijar4IJgzBYO4JykHK3AMgqnDSQaACcnCbNwKrnEi8TGqapDmgyVqsmOYn2o687mW6noQEgnQEB4A7kJQIZ%2BgGgiYPgRDoWujAsM224AO5Th4MXGsJYW2r0UiiiMxWEAgIwSUiUkyXJogKUpL5mS6FlWTZlC0vSgXBaFWYRYoUXOlKspmGsCqOZIDJrOcoprNwaySJqvDGlBInhXa0X9bF8Dul66VhoGaU%2BhlFTAJ5FjJqwqbppmtY5mexA1kWJZlpW1YtpgDaiM2tatu2eCdl%2BY69v2g7LsOoKjsyrATlOP0zn0RYLkuK5JnQBWblwvACEajYoAe8jo8e8DtO%2Bn7HaRUNwQhVFBMh2iMcRGF4QUrF82Efg8%2BhLOwYULEc0heSs5L7FRGhlRS4EMsNAxHHNMRPECvxhmCYyzLVW%2B9Kte1IzAMgyAjJ5CqSApam5QZ2m6fdxCaZIRnU31c32WYDIG2NIAhYdNWRU6MUXfFICJclBCpcGd3XWYlg5SQgj5RuRW8KVzDlUjI2G6HJu1SK9uNQQzVm9JFtWzbmx2z7NLtJZ1kVHZAVmsHE2iczM3mfNK0GwdxtTbNrpR3FSBXQGCczxU/TIB4HhRv0nBuVGkjnFGrVJimbjvVmX35nO/30IDNZjvWjbg1feBtskMPdn2yADjjyNwqjR6Y3m2NznjQ5VxEyzluMmIA7x7ipiZGmE4Tx2UZn4L80EyJs20ILFCmslbxEwgLaWuFhYREwVxGiKD5Y1DwSRWi5EFacSYooFW1E2Ia0VsQ/WvFBQCUqkbSapttQjCMAoReIw15uTtucB2ad3Z1XiDpJO%2Bk6prC9tApur45RD07kFbuxcpoOgjqdKOCUBxxznnIiod5srqTysAwqoDSC53zgTLh2j6QKIak1FqfCBFCJEWIlRLdBrt0LkHEOo8%2B56N9mogO%2B1uG916H4g2kgYlHTiSdX2D4fAaG4EAA%3D):

```
void PrintValue(int*);

void f() {
  int numSides = 3;
  int *valPointer;
  *valPointer = &numSides;
  PrintValue(valPointer);
}
```

### Compilation results:

Clang:

```
<source>:6:17: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int *'; remove &
  *valPointer = &numSides;
                ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Gcc:

```
<source>: In function 'void f()':
<source>:6:17: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
    6 |   *valPointer = &numSides;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 int*
Compiler returned: 1
```

Microsoft compiler:

```
example.cpp
<source>(6): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'
<source>(6): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
Compiler returned: 2
```

Each compiler in it's own way says what the problem is in the error messages.

- incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int *'
- invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
- cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'

Clang even gives a suggestion:

- remove '&'

Which is not necessarily correct.

Answer (score 0):

> int *valPointer = &numSides;

This declares a variable, `valPointer`, of type `int *`, and stores the address of `numSides` in it.

> int* valPointer;
> *valPointer = &numSides;

This declares a variable, `valPointer`, of type `int *`, but doesn't initialize it to point to any particular location. The address it contains is just whatever garbage happened to be on the stack. It then dereferences `valPointer`, which is an error because `valPointer` was never initialized, and tries to store the address of `numSides` in that location.

I think the essential point you need is that `*` is used to dereference a pointer when used alone (e.g. `*valPointer`), but it's part of the type when used in a declaration (e.g. `int *valPointer`). Also, note that when used in a declaration it doesn't matter whether there's space between the type and `*` or the `*` and variable; that is, `int *foo` and `int *foo` mean the same thing.